# Array Changing to String When Updating Value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I have a  list on my HTML page.  This list pulls from an array using ng-options.  One of the object array's properties is show.  The ng-options uses a filter to only display options where show == 1.  When the user hits a button the select item in the list is added to an array and the show value needs to be set to 0 so it is removed from the list. The value is being set to 0 but the ng-options is now printing the options for the select incorrectly.

**Array Definition**

```
referenceTypes: Array<any> = [
            { label: 'Customer Reference', show: 1 },
            { label: 'PO Number', show: 1 },
            { label: 'SO Number', show: 1 }
        ]
```

**Button Click**

```
addReferenceType = () => {
            ... 

            // hide the reference type from the add drop down list
            this.referenceTypes.filter(option => option.label == this.referenceType)[0].show = 0;
        }
```

**HTML**

```
<select ng-model='$ctrl.referenceType'
        ng-options="option.label as option.label for option in $ctrl.referenceTypes | filter: {show: 1}">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

**Before**
[image: Before]

**After**
[image: After]

Comment: Hi, I tried your code it appears to be working correctly for me.
Could you create a working example so that we can reproduce the issue. Please check the below link
[tried sample on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/25z9ck4n/2)

Comment: @KRISHNAPATEL the jsfiddle you created has the following error when clicking on the select: `Cannot set property 'show' of undefined`

Comment: @KRISHNAPATEL you need to change your code in this way, otherwise one time the `filter` returns an empty array and you have that error, because the `click` is triggered twice. `addReferenceType() {
          let filteredTypes: Array<any> = this.referenceTypes.filter(option => option.label == this.referenceType);
          if (filteredTypes.length > 0) {
            filteredTypes[0].show = 0;
          }
        }`

Comment: @quirimmo Can you add this as an answer? It will be better for everyone to see the code.

Comment: @BrunoPoeta thanks for your message. Done even if I am not so sure that this fixes the user issue is too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change your code in this way, otherwise one time the filter returns an empty array and you have that error, because the click is triggered twice.

```
addReferenceType() { 
    let filteredTypes: Array<any> = 
    this.referenceTypes.filter(option => option.label == this.referenceType); 
    if (filteredTypes.length > 0) { 
        filteredTypes[0].show = 0; 
    } 
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, this was my mistake.  The code I posted works fine.  There was a second div which was being shown when another array length was greater than 0 and the code I wrote was being hidden.  They look the same from a UI standpoint so I didn't even notice.  

@quirimmo there was some issues with your fiddle but the solution provided does essentially the same thing.  I will give you some credit anyway!